# Maximum tensor rank

Tags: tensor-products, tensors, tensor-rank

According to wikipedia, it is unknown what the maximal rank of a tensor is in the space $F^{n_{1}} \otimes ... \otimes F^{n_{k}}$. It is quite easy to show that it is at most 
$$\prod _{i=1} ^{k} n_{i}/\max\left(n_{i}\right)$$
Since $F^{n_{1}} \otimes ... \otimes F^{n_{k}}=F^{n_{1}} \otimes V $ where $V=F^{n_{2}} \otimes ... \otimes F^{n_{k}}$ and supposing $n_{1}$ is maximal this gives the bound above.
I am interested in the case where $n_{1}=...=n_{k}$, simply call it $n$. Can we do better in this case. That is, can we show whether

1. The bound $n^{k-1}$ is tight,
2. if not, is there a stronger bound?

*Edit: The bound above follows since the rank in $U\otimes V$ is at most $\dim\left(U\right)$ and at most $\dim\left(V\right)$.

Comment: What do you mean "at most $\max\left(n_i\right)$"? This doesn't sound like a correct statement. The maximum rank of a tensor in $F^2 \otimes F^2 \otimes F^2$ is $3$, not $\leq 2$ (over $\mathbb{R}$).

Comment: You're right, my bad. I believe it is all correct now.

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/102559/what-is-the-largest-tensor-rank-of-n-times-n-times-n-tensor: the maximum rank in $(F^n)^{\otimes 3}$ is at most $\binom{n+1}{2}$ (maybe smaller, that is still an open question). I think that there are very few cases where the actual maximum rank is known, for example $F^2 \otimes F^b \otimes F^c$ and a few others, but for "most" tensor products it's still wide open.